# Is it possible to compare Colors and if they resemble return true

Tags: java, if-statement, colors, compare

An example of what I mean would be:

```
Color maroon = #800000;
Color red = #ff0000;

if (red <resembles> maroon) //which would return true because they're both red colors.{
//...
} else {
System.out.println("The colors did not resemble.");
}
```

Would this be possible and if so then how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Yes, if you write a method that implements such a logic.

Comment: How *much* redness would there need to be for the test to pass? Would any admixture of other colours be permitted?

Comment: And how would you go about specifying *normality*? What you currently say is too subjective. For example your 'marron' [sic] would look redder against a black background than a green one.

Comment: A statement like `Color maroon = #800000;` is not valid Java.

Comment: @Jesper I know that, it was just an example of an hex, I haven't used Colors much but will be in the future.

Comment: @FOD What would a normal person like you define red as?

Comment: @bot Red would be like blood, apples, strawberries, etc.

Comment: @FOD Tell that to a computer. You think it would understand? The point I am trying to make is that you are the one who has to tell your program what red is. That's the point everyone is making but somehow, you fail to understand it. You need to decide what red is. After that, it's just a matter of few lines of code.

Comment: @bot You could probably do that with a lot of code, which is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem isn't so much about programming but about physiology and psychology of color-perception.

Comment: @FOD "As much as a normal person would call the color red or reddish" there is an absolutely wonderful episode of [Fry's English Delight](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b01lv4ng) which discusses the difference in colour perception between speakers of different languages. It's a fascinating programme to listen to.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think the best way would be to simply compare the red components:

```
public boolean checkIfSimilar(Color c1, Color c2) {
    int threshold = 10;
    if(c1.getRed() - c2.getRed() < threshold){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You just define your threshold depending on how much you want those colors to be similar.

Comment: Bull! Red would compare against white! Seriously, this is a difficult field, the stuff of PhD studies.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this without some degree of subjectivity: there is no single notion of "red". Even for the examples you give above (blood, apples, strawberries), one can give examples which are not red (e.g. [lobster blood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lobster#Description) is blue, the [Granny Smith varietal of apple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granny_Smith_apple) is green, [underripe strawberries](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=under%20ripe%20strawberries&tbm=isch) are green), and even the appearance of "red" examples of these things is quite different depending upon lighting conditions.

You need to determine what you consider "red" to be in a way that is sufficient for your application. This will probably require the comparison of the components of the color to the components of an "ideal redness"; however, you could use a far more advanced technique such as using some machine learning model. Given the way in which you have asked the question, I assume you are looking for a rather basic solution.

You should consider using a different color space to RGB. For example, [HSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) (Hue Saturation Lightness) gives you something resembling a normalized color in its first component (the "hue"). You could compare this hue to some reference value of redness, and you get brightness-invariant comparison.

The two main caveats I would mention with HSL:

1. Hue is a circular space, i.e. you need to consider the wrapping of its value in determining the distance from a reference point;
2. Checking the saturation is important, since hue is undefined for a "color" such as white or black.